# Comando não funciona quando executado via cronjob

Tags: linux, ssh

Estou tentando criar um *cronjob* que executa o seguinte comando

```
sudo sh /usr/local/bin/send_site_backup_files_to_dropbox.sh |
ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" 2>&1 |
tee /var/log/send_backups_to_dropbox.log |
mailx -s "Report for Vesta backup files sent to Dropbox" meu@email.com`
```

O comando executa um *script* que faz o upload dos backups do meu servidor para minha pasta no *dropbox*. Funciona perfeitamente quando eu o executo pelo *PuTTy*. Porém quando é executado via cronjob é retornado para meu email o seguinte erro:

> ```
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
> /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
> ```

Sem essa parte `ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" 2>&1` ele funciona, então o problema está aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape o `%`:

`"[\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S]"`

[Leia mais aqui](http://www.hcidata.info/crontab.htm)

---

Outra alternativa:

Crie um arquivo com o que será executado pela rotina:

executarotina.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sh /usr/local/bin/send_site_backup_files_to_dropbox.sh |
ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" 2>&1 |
tee /var/log/send_backups_to_dropbox.log |
mailx -s "Report for Vesta backup files sent to Dropbox" meu@email.com`
```

No seu crontab, chame o arquivo `executarotina.sh`

Comment: Muito obrigado, a segunda alternativa foi a que funcionou. Na primeira ainda apresenta o mesmo erro.